# After installing Ubuntu 11.10, laptop just restart to POST or go to Internal Shell

Tags: 11.10, boot, dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

Ok, i have been using **Ubuntu** since 8.04 on my old laptop, but some months ago i got a new one and since that day i'm having some bad times.

First lemme describe it. It's a **CCE** (*brazilian brand*) **WM545B-T** with **4gb DDR3**, **Intel i5 Sandy Bridge 2500k** iirc, **Intel HD 3000** (*great integrated card btw*) and a **500gb 5200rpm HD** (*yeah, i know...*). It's motherboard is, iirc, a **Intel HM65**.

As i reported in a question before, when i first got it, i tryed to install **Ubuntu 11.04** and got some weird screen bugs. I got around that installing **SuperOS**, a **Ubuntu 11.04** based distro.

Yesterday at 8am (*brazil time*) i saw some **Ubuntu CDs** from the oficial release repos (*before the oficial release by Canonical*), downloaded via torrent, checked md5 and used unetbootin to burn it to a pendrive.

Started the install like i always do any other OS install, the weird screen bug was there again... but this time i was able to click the first option and start the **Live CD**. Great... i was finally gonna use my loved distro again. Oh man, i was wrong.

The **Live CD** worked great and insanely fast. I runned the installer and went to the advanced options for partitions.
I have 3 NTFS partitions... one with 20gb for **W7 64bits**, one with 100mb with **system files** that **W7** created and the rest is for my personal files. Made a 25gb ext4 one for **Ubuntu** and a 4gb swap one. The bottom of the install ask me where i wanna install the bootloader, with **/dev/sda** (*my hd*) by default. Then installed it and the install went without a problem. Made me happy ofc.

When the laptop was booting again, the first problem. It did not boot... just freeze at post or restart. Ok... went to the **Live CD** again and this time tryed a different setup for my partitions.

Tryed to install the bootloader in **/dev/sda2**, with **Windows Boot Loader**. This time it booted... but on a **EFI Shell**, something i have no idea about what is. Tryed again... created swap, ext4 for **Ubuntu** and this time also created a **EFI partition** (*i thought Hey, it says EFI, lets try it lol*)... same **EFI Shell** saying something about **startup.sh** and then gimme a **Shell> *inpurt commands here*** line of command.

I have never see this **EFI Shell** before and i can't find infos about it on the internet. Not infos i can use to install Ubuntu at least. Anyone know what is that or how can i install my lovely distro?

**Right now i have some options in mind:**
1. Format my **ENTIRE** HD losing 232gb of important fles and try to install **Ubuntu 11.10** on the entire HD to see what happens;
2. Install **W7** from zero and install **Ubuntu** with **Wubi** losing performance with it;
3. Use **Fedora** (*that install and boot normaly*) or some **Ubuntu 11.10** distro based (that will take sometime to appear);
4. Delete my **W7** partition, install **Ubuntu 11.10** and then install **W7** again... recover grub and see what happens...

Anyone have an answer for this question before i try one of those ideas? My obvious idea is the problem is based on my boot since the **Live CD** works ok and other distros based on **Ubuntu** runs fine.
I have tested **Ubuntu 10.10** and give me same **11.04** issues... but **ElemetaryOS**, based on **10.10**, works fine. I don't know what tweak they do on the boot... but something happens there.
Anyone have an answer for this?

EDIT: Ok, i think i may know what is going on.
Runned `sudo fdisk -l` and this is what i get from it:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2b510800

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    40962047    20377600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       102402048   976771071   437184512    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        40964094   102402047    30718977    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        94191616   102402047     4105216   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6        40964096    94189567    26612736   83  Linux
```

If you take a close look, there is no "*", so maybe it means there is no boot device set? Then when i try to boot from HD it doesn't find any bootable device and give me the internal shell (EFI Shell). Anyone can help me fix this?

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer!

Comment: My oh my, that's a lot of emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved the problem. Probably did not used the best solution but well... at least it's booting and stuffs. What i did was delete **Windows** and **Ubuntu** partitions, make new one for both, install **Ubuntu** and then install **W7**... then restaured grub and done. Ubuntu working.

**Edit:** Answering it here as i have been told to ;)